# How can I mod Skyrim on a different drive?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I modded my Skyrim on my C: drive awhile back and it ended up breaking. I didn't have space on my C: drive to continue modding anyways, so I re-downloaded Skyrim to my D: drive, but I don't know how to mod it from there.

Is there a way to move my current mods from my C: to my D: and they would work? I typically use Nexus Mod Manager for my mods, but I'm not sure if that would be an option anymore. Also, will I be able to still use FNIS and other programs like it?

Comment: NMM should have an option to search for/point to a new location.

Comment: Also, clean up your C drive. Empty your trash. I've seen upwards of 100GB in the Recycle bin before.

Comment: I thought the D: in the title was an unhappy smiley and was about to edit it out...Reminder, must not edit things before my morning coffee.

Comment: If you use LOOT or another loadorder program to automatically change the loot order, make sure you do this aswell.

Answer (score 2):

As @SaintWacko said you just need to update where NMM thinks your installation of Skyrim is at and then it should continue to work like normal. If the auto-scan does not pick up the game then you should be able to enter it in manually.